# How to auto prompt enter key with yes no thereafter in script ksh

Tags: ksh, aix

I have a command within a script that prompts a user to hit enter key 1st with yes no thereafter. Creating a basic script to auto answer yes no questions is not a problem. I am finding it difficult to find the command to automate a script with the enter prompt key.

The prompts are below:

```
Please mount tape 1 on /ddomain/data/centdctst1/centdctst1/data and press Return to continue ...
Continue restore? (y/n)
Do you want to back up the logs? (y/n)
Restore a level 1 archive (y/n)
```

To automate the process, I can use the below:

```
ontape -p <<!
<enter key command>
y
n
n
!
```

Using the above in a script does not work. I am looking for a method of hitting enter then following the yes no questions.

Comment: If I use my command and just use yes in place of enter key the restore does work, however is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Does it work if you simply pass an empty line, so simply press enter after you open up the here-doc ? Apart from that, you can also try with `ontape -p -d` which should suppress interactive prompts.